# How to configure Nlog.config to pick configuration changes automatically at runtime

Tags: asp.net, nlog

Each time the NLog file is modified (during the development time) with different target parameters such as `layout`, changes are not immediately reflected in the output. To see the affected result, I had to restart the `IIS` and re-run the web application.

How to configure the `NLog.config` to read the changes automatically?

Answer (score 1):

`NLog.config` can be configured to read the configuration parameters each time the file is modified. Include the `autoReload="true"` parameter to the NLog.config file

```html
<nlog autoReload="true">
 . . . 
</nlog>
```

Reference : 
Refer the section **[Automatic reconfiguration](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file)**